# Beamer: TOC only once before sections with subsections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

My presentation consist of multiple sections. Some sections consist of subsection and some not. I want beamer to display the TOC before every subsection and before every section which consists of no other subsection.

Currently, i write in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhalt} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]  
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhalt} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsubsection]  
    \end{frame}
}
```

As a result, if a section consist of subsecitons beamer displays the TOC twice before the first subsection in a section, one time for the section and one time for the subsection. That is ugly in my opinion. What can i do?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795478/latex-beamer-prevent-showing-the-toc-at-one-occation

Answer (score 11):

You can very simply use TeX conditionals. The only drawback (or feature) is that for section with subsections, in the first ToC does not "shade" the latter subsections. Basically, we tell LaTeX: At section, make ToC and remember `false`. At subsection, if you see `true` make ToC, and remember `true`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\iflattersubsect

\AtBeginSection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhalt} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]  
    \end{frame}
    \lattersubsectfalse
}

\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \iflattersubsect
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhalt} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsubsection]  
    \end{frame}
    \fi
    \lattersubsecttrue
}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}

\section{SECT I}
\subsection{I.1}
\begin{frame}I.1\end{frame}

\subsection{I.2}
\begin{frame}I.2\end{frame}

\section{SECT II}
\begin{frame}II frame 1\end{frame}
\begin{frame}II frame 2\end{frame}

\section{SECT III}
\subsection{III.1}
\begin{frame}III.1\end{frame}

\subsection{III.2}
\begin{frame}III.2\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple test could check if the `sectionstartpage` equals the `subsectionstartpage` and act accordingly. The following example will in this case hide the toc of the section, but hiding the subsection toc would work in the same way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[] {
    \ifnum\insertsubsectionstartpage=\insertsectionstartpage
        \relax%
    \else%
      \begin{frame}<beamer>
      \frametitle{Inhalt} %
      \tableofcontents[currentsection]  
      \end{frame}
  \fi%
}

\AtBeginSubsection[] {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Inhalt} %
    \tableofcontents[currentsubsection]  
    \end{frame}
}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}

\section{SECT I}
\subsection{I.1}
\begin{frame}I.1\end{frame}

\subsection{I.2}
\begin{frame}I.2\end{frame}

\section{SECT II}
\begin{frame}II frame 1\end{frame}
\begin{frame}II frame 2\end{frame}

\section{SECT III}
\subsection{III.1}
\begin{frame}III.1\end{frame}

\subsection{III.2}
\begin{frame}III.2\end{frame}

\end{document}
```