# Show ToC for each section only if there is no subsection

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

In Beamer, I used the following code to show ToC at the beginning of each section.

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>[allowframebreaks]{Outline} 
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Then the problem is the ToC is not shown at the last section 'Conclusion' because there is no subsection under 'Conclusion' section.

So I used the following code to show ToC at the beginning of each section.

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>[allowframebreaks]{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Now the problem is ToC is shown twice at the beginning of 'normal' sections (with subsections).
How can I show ToC at the beginning of Section 'only if' there is no subsection under it?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85900/beamer-toc-only-once-before-sections-with-subsections?rq=1 and this mentions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795478/latex-beamer-prevent-showing-the-toc-at-one-occation

Comment: Can you make a MWE?